# CKEditor integration with laravel-filemanager

Tags: ckeditor, laravel-5

I'm using [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) and [laravel-filemanager](https://github.com/tsawler/laravel-filemanager), which is a nice package written for Laravel. Anyway, I'm having trouble passing the URL of the selected image from the filemanager browser to the URL field in the plugin dialog in CKEditor. I did everything included in the README file of the laravel-filemanager, but I had no luck.
This [link](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/File_Browser_%28Uploader%29/Custom_File_Browser) says I should use predefined route for 'filebrowserBrowseUrl=' in the CKEditor and the rest of the params in the query string is auto-generated like:

'myRoute/?type=Images&CKEditor=editor1&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en'.

My problem is that there is no 'CKEditorFuncNum' param in the url. When I click the 'Browse Server' button, pop-up window is opened with url: 'myRoute', with the query string params missing. Anyone familiar with CKEditor and laravel-filemanager knows what's going on when the pop-up window is opened. The 'CKEditorFuncNum' param is retreived by regex and then the function gets executed and the URL is passed to the editor dialog.

Since no URL is set in my case, clearly I'm missing something. If anyone knows something more, please share it with me, 'cause this is very annoying.

Thanks in advance